# Java swing, test state of a button?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a method that will toggle a button from being disabled to being enabled and back using a simple if statement.

I would assume that it would be something like

```
if (buttonDisable.setEnabled(true) == true){
    //do stuff
}
```

But I haven't had much luck finding my answer via google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't test the display of the model, test the model.

```
if (buttonDisable.getModel().isEnabled()) {
  // do stuff
}
```

That way if you change the model, you avoid a level of dispatch (view --- updates ---> model --- updates ---> view(s))

A better solution is to make your model changes independent of the view.  This way you don't get tied into requiring a specific view to be present to make the model change.

```
ButtonModel toggle = new ButtonModel();
...
JButton button = new JButton(toggle);
...
// this is clear that we are manipulating the model, not the view
// as new views are added / removed, this toggle will continue to work
toggle.setEnabled(!toggle.isEnabled());
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just toggle the state in one shot:

```
buttonDisable.setEnabled(!buttonDisable.isEnabled())
```